# Is there a way to change the source of an html video object without making it look glitchy?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

I'm trying to make something like a video call interface, but I'm playing videos that get generated based on user responses. I need to be able to switch between the video currently displayed to the next generated video without the HTML collapsing and rebuilding the video element.

I tried just to change the source of the video using javascript and hoped that it would lead to a seamless transition, but that led to the video "collapsing" and then forming again.

The javascript looks something like this:

```
const video_html = document.getElementById('video');
function changeSource(path){
        video_html.src = path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need to be able to switch between the video currently displayed to the next generated video without the HTML collapsing and rebuilding the video element."*

The natural state of the MPEG video decoder is to re-initialize for new data. This cannot be avoided so you need a workaround (and that depends on how advanced you are as a coder or video engineer).

**(1)** If all the video clips already exist, and need only to be dynamically selected...

**Easiest:** Switch between two video tags:

- Use two `<video>` tags to hold a "now playing" and a "next playing" video.
- Control "visibilty" by using CSS Styles (in Javascript *eg:* `myvid.style.visibility = "hidden"`).
- Use CSS options: `z-index`, `position`, `top`, `left`, to position one video tag above another.

**Easier:** Seek to different clips  within one video file:

- Compile (or join) all videos into one long video file.
- Loop according to time-range of each clip (check curren time via `timeupdate` event).
- If next clip is needed, then **seek to that time** within the video and repeat your loop function.

**(2)** If the video clips are dynamically generated (eg: lip sync for custom response's  words)...

**Harder:** Use MediaSource Extensions to feed each video as a chunk:

- Export (or convert) your videos into Fragmented MP4.
- In MSE, first feed it with the main header (an initial MOOV atom).
- Then feed in the clip (as a chunk) that you need to be looped.
- To change videos, just feed in the bytes of a different video.

Feeding in video bytes with MSE does not force the `<video>` tag to reload. 
It expects to be occasionally receiving video data so it stays "open" all the time.

An alternative to using MSE is to instead use PHP to feed video bytes into a `<video>` tag. This means using a `.php` as video source instead of a `.mp4` file.

The MSE and PHP methods require you to know about MP4 file structure (is multiple byte-values inside an Array, and byte just means a number between 0 and 255). You need to learn which bytes represent your file's header and which bytes are the audio/video frames.