# Looping animations HTM5 - replacing video only after current video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html5-video

[image]

I have the following code where it shows an orb animation on loop. I want to be able to control the changes in animation so that if I click on the seeding/deepsearch buttons it changes the video ONLY after the current animation has finished. Need to include maybe preloading of videos and event bubbling handling to avoid trying to switch different animations whilst one is still playing. Maybe take on the very latest button clicked animation - skip trying to play an earlier click.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-thunder-czctj7

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 



<script> 

  let animationStackObject = [{
      "state":"idol",
      "path": "./orb2/idol.mp4"
    },
    {
      "state":"seeding",
      "path": "./orb2/seeding.mp4"
    },
    {
      "state": "deepsearch",
      "path": "./orb2/deepsearch.mp4"
    }
  ]



  let videoController = {
    vid: document.getElementById("myVideo"),
    init: function(){
      //let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
      //vid.src = getAnimation("idol", animationStackObject)

      //setCurrentState("idol");
      //this.playVid()
      //playVideo()//loopable
    },
    getAnimation: function(state, animationStackObject){
     //-- return animationStackElement of correct state requested
    },
    playVid: function() {
      let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
      vid.play();
      console.log(vid.duration);
      console.log(vid.currentTime);
      //duration of video in 1 loop is 5 seconds - start a timer
    },
    pauseVid: function() { 
      let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
      vid.pause();  
    },
    videoEnded: function() {
      console.log("The End.");
      this.playVid()
    },
    changeMood: function(state){
      //is video still playing

      //at point video has finished break loop and send new video to be played
      
      //setCurrentState("idol");
      //change current video to new video path
      //play loop
      console.log(state);
      this.changeVideo();
    },
    changeVideo: function() {
      //

      var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
      var source = document.createElement('source');

      source.setAttribute('src', './orb2/idol.mp4');
      source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

      vid.innerHTML = "";
      //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "whatever";

      vid.appendChild(source);
      vid.play();
      console.log({
        src: source.getAttribute('src'),
        type: source.getAttribute('type'),
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        vid.pause();

        source.setAttribute('src', './orb2/seeding.mp4');
        source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

        vid.load();
        vid.play();
        console.log({
          src: source.getAttribute('src'),
          type: source.getAttribute('type'),
        });
      }, 3000);



      //
    }
  }

  videoController.init();

</script> 


<button onclick="videoController.playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
<button onclick="videoController.pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> 

loop
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" onended="videoController.videoEnded()">
  <source src="./orb2/idol.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('Idol')">Idol</button>
<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('Seeding')">Seeding</button>
<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('DeepSearch')">DeepSearch</button>


</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the latest button click into a variable, and only change the source when the current video ends:

```js
let animationStackObject = [
  {
    "state": "idol",
    "path": "https://czctj7.csb.app/orb2/idol.mp4"
  },
  {
    "state": "seeding",
    "path": "https://czctj7.csb.app/orb2/seeding.mp4"
  },
  {
    "state": "deepsearch",
    "path": "https://czctj7.csb.app/orb2/deepsearch.mp4"
  }
];

// Store which video will play next. Null means continue the
// current video.
let next = null;

let videoController = {
  vid: document.getElementById("myVideo"),
  init: function() {
    //let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    //vid.src = getAnimation("idol", animationStackObject)

    //setCurrentState("idol");
    //this.playVid()
    //playVideo()//loopable
  },
  getAnimation: function(state, animationStackObject) {
    //-- return animationStackElement of correct state requested
  },
  playVid: function() {
    let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.play();
    console.log(vid.duration);
    console.log(vid.currentTime);
    //duration of video in 1 loop is 5 seconds - start a timer
  },
  pauseVid: function() {
    let vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    vid.pause();
  },
  videoEnded: function() {
    console.log("The End.");
    // If there is a different video selected,
    // switch to it.
    if (next) {
      this.changeVideo(next);
      next = null;
    }
    this.playVid()
  },
  changeMood: function(state) {
    //is video still playing

    //at point video has finished break loop and send new video to be played

    //setCurrentState("idol");
    //change current video to new video path
    //play loop
    console.log(state);
    next = state.toLowerCase();
  },
  changeVideo: function(which) {
    const vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    const source = vid.querySelector('source');
    
    source.setAttribute('src', animationStackObject.find(({ state }) => state === which).path);
    
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
    
    console.log({
      src: source.getAttribute('src'),
      type: source.getAttribute('type'),
    });
  }
}

videoController.init();
```

```html
<button onclick="videoController.playVid()" type="button">Play Video</button>
<button onclick="videoController.pauseVid()" type="button">Pause Video</button><br> loop
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" onended="videoController.videoEnded()">
  <source src="https://czctj7.csb.app/orb2/idol.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('Idol')">Idol</button>
<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('Seeding')">Seeding</button>
<button onClick="videoController.changeMood('DeepSearch')">DeepSearch</button>
```

Comment: The transition between the videos should be seamless - it goes white before showing the new video. Do we need to preload the videos? Could we get it to autoplay at the start.

Comment: It also blinks even if you select the same video

Comment: Yes, you'd need to preload the videos. You could try to get it to autoplay at the start.

Comment: @TheOldCounty See if [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76583226/2057709) are helpful to you..